# Module not properly instantiated?

Tags: verilog

I have an example code about T-Bird Tail Lights, and it's passing states to the next module. I modified the code that it doesn't have to pass the state, but it seems the output is not changing(stays 000 all the time)

Here's my modified code:

```
module TBird(E,B,L,R,int_clk,L_Light,R_Light);
input E,B,L,R,int_clk;
output [2:0] L_Light;
output [0:2] R_Light;
reg [19:0] C;
wire int_clk;

One_Side U1 (E,B,R,int_clk,R_Light);
One_Side U2 (E,B,L,int_clk,L_Light);
endmodule

module One_Side(e,b,t,clk,light_eb);
input e,b,t,clk;
output reg [2:0] light_eb=3'b000;
always @(posedge clk or e or b or t)
    begin
        case ({e,b,t})
        3'b000: light_eb=3'b000;
        3'b0?1: begin
                    if (light_eb==3'b000) begin
                        light_eb=3'b001;
                    end else if (light_eb==3'b001) begin
                        light_eb=3'b011;
                    end else if(light_eb==3'b011) begin
                        light_eb=3'b111;
                    end else begin
                        light_eb=3'b000;
                    end
                end
        3'b?10: light_eb=3'b111;
        3'b10?: begin
                    if (light_eb!==(3'b000|3'b111)) begin
                        light_eb=3'b000;
                    end
                    light_eb=~light_eb;
                end
        3'b111: begin
                    if (light_eb==3'b000) begin
                        light_eb=3'b001;
                    end else if (light_eb==3'b001) begin
                        light_eb=3'b011;
                    end else if(light_eb==3'b011) begin
                        light_eb=3'b111;
                    end else begin
                        light_eb=3'b000;
                    end
                end
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```

I have had some experience in Java, but I don't know much about verilog, so I don't even know where goes wrong(in Java, eclipse has break points and debugger and things like that,) any suggestions/recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: `always @(posedge clk or e or b or t)` should be `always @(posedge clk)` for synchronous logic. or `always @*` for combinational logic. Pick one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of mistakes in the testbench and design. Listed down as follows:

You have **not provided any toggling on clock signal**. So there will not be any `posedge` of clock detected. There are many *ways for generating clock*, one of them is as follows:

```
always #5 clk = ~clk;
```

Using a `reset` signal in design is good practice. Apply **reset** from testbench to set all the i**nternal registers in design** to their **initial values**.

The most **important** thing is you have **not provided any input stimulus** to the design. Any **random stimulus** must be applied to get the output. You have to provide some inputs to get the output, henceforth your output is `x`.

```
initial
begin
forever
begin
  #6;
  E = $random;
  B = $random;
  R = $random; // and so on...
end
end
```

Use of **nonblocking (<=) assignments** in design is a good coding practice. Also, **donot mix blocking (=) and nonblocking (<=) assignments**.

```
a = b; // never use this in sequential circuit.
a<= b; // use this in sequential circuit.
```

I have made a somewhat valid testbench for your design, have a look at [EDAPlayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Gvf) link.

Must refer to [this](http://www.slideshare.net/Abhishekt11/test-bench-development), [this](http://read.pudn.com/downloads149/ebook/643578/Writing%20testbenches%20using%20SystemVerilog.pdf), and [this](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/first1.html) links for understanding **general testbench architecture**.